# How to union different multiple selects in one query?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to combine all the tables in one or maybe two queries?

I tried to use union but i need access to each row in query.

And the biggest problem for me is to sort all of this with ORDER BY.

For example i need to print first query rows in one div, second query rows in another div and so on..

```
(SELECT 
      link as RelLink, 
      date as RelDate,
      title as RelTitle 
   FROM torrent 
   WHERE moderate = 1 
   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,12),
(SELECT 
      torrent as TorLink1, 
      date as TorDate1, 
      title as TorTitle1 
   FROM torrents 
   WHERE moderate = 1 AND genre = 1 
   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10),
(SELECT 
      date as TorDate2, 
      torrent as TorLink2, 
      title as TorTitle2 
   FROM torrents 
   WHERE moderate = 1 AND genre = 2 
   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10),
(SELECT 
      link as NewsLink1, 
      date as NewsDate1, 
      title as NewsTitle1 
   FROM news 
   WHERE moderate = 1
   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10),
(SELECT 
      link as NewsLink2, 
      date as NewsDate2,
      title as NewsTitle2 
   FROM news 
   WHERE moderate = 1 
   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10,10);
```

Comment: so why not remove the commas and put in UNION and then add one final ORDER BY at the end to order by all of them after limiting? not sure I understand your question

Comment: it joins all rows in one table, but in result i wanna use different tables like it was with single query.
i know i can use TEMPORARY TABLE, but i don't want to do that =\

Comment: have you looked into views?

Comment: I go to google right now..

Comment: Why not use separate queries? Much more clear and concise, and not really a performance penalty as a union will effectively run the queries multiple times and join them up... in fact because you are using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`, the query will filter out duplicates which will add some time to the query.

Comment: @Lock from what I can see there aren't any unions.. it looks like either a bunch of correlated subqueries or a cartesian product ... both of which will take a long time.

Comment: @JohnRuddell- I should learn to read before replying. I just read it again and I am convinced they should be separate queries.

Comment: @Lock the OP has a very poorly worded question... my recommendation is to make each one a view and then query from them... but I dono why the OP even needs to do these.. seems like you could do it in one select with a row counter and case statements...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do what you ask. You need `UNION ALL` between your queries. You also need to use the same aliases for your columns in each of the items you're `UNION`ing together.

Here's what will do the job for you.  I didn't repeat all your subqueries

```
SELECT Link, Date, Title 
FROM (
    SELECT link as Link, date as Date, title as Title 
      FROM torrent  WHERE moderate = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,12
    UNION ALL
    SELECT torrent as Link, date as Date, title as Title 
      FROM torrents  WHERE moderate = 1 AND genre = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT torrent as Link, date as Date, title as Title
      FROM torrents WHERE moderate = 1 AND genre = 2 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10 
    UNION ALL
   /* etc etc */
) AS query
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Notice how all the columns are made to conform to each other by using the same aliases?

If you want these items deduplicated, use `UNION` rather that `UNION ALL`.  It's a little slower because of the deduplication process, but you're only handling dozens of rows so that's likely not a problem.